# Django on a subdomain

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, django-urls, uwsgi

I am trying to get django to work on a subdomain.  It can render the main page (r^$ in the urls.py file) just fine, nut the rest of the pages I get 404 errors.  And not the typical 404 errors.  These pages are extremely plain...

They look the same, but the only thing listed below the yellow header is:

```
{'path': u'people/'}.
```

This is what I would get when I would try to go to sub.example.com/people.

Does django really not handle subdomains at all, or is this a problem with my server configuration.  I am using nginx and uwsgi, but since the django 404 pages are loading I feel this is a django issue.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name sub.example.com;

  # Error pages
  # error_page 500 502 503 504 /;

  location root {
        root   html;
        uwsgi_pass   127.0.0.1:49154;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT django_wsgi;
        include        uwsgi_params;
    }

  location / {
        uwsgi_pass   127.0.0.1:49154;
        include        uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT mysite.wsgi:application;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know uwsgi at all, but setting `SCRIPT_NAME` explicitly to `/` sounds wrong.

Comment: that worries me too, but the nginx/uwsgi application seems to be working well... django error pages are rendered, and the webpages that they look for the url for are correct... so my guess is this might be a django/subdomain issue.

Comment: What happens if you remove this line: `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /;` ?

Comment: I ended up removing both uwsgi_params to make it work... I have a .ini file for the uwsgi_params already so it was a duplicate param problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was nginx sends these params to uwsgi.  If you follow the Django uwsig page you will see that they have you make a .ini file with the uwsgi params already.  So django users should leave out the UWSGI params part on the nginx file